# On click on the Google Login button in my react hooks page, nothing is happening

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on the `Google Login` button in my react hooks login, below error is displaying. Can someone please advise what could be the problem here ? Below is the warning and error details

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Now getting an error:

```
react-dom.development.js:3832 Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.``

Check the render method of `Login`.
```

`Login.js`

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useGoogleLogin  } from 'react-google-login';
import { refreshToken } from '../utils/refreshToken';

const clientId ="client_id_here";

const Login = () => {

    const onSuccess = (res) =>{
        console.log("Login successfully",res.profileObj);
        refreshToken(res);
    }
    const onFailure = (res) => {
        console.log('Login failed: res:', res);
        alert(
            `Failed to login.`
        );
    };
    const {signIn, loaded} = useGoogleLogin ({
        onSuccess,
        onFailure,
        clientId,
        isSignedIn: true,
        accessType: 'offline',
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="inputForm">
                <button onClick={()=>signIn}>
                    <img src="images/google.png" className="loginG"/>
                    <span className="loginText">Sign in</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

`src/utils/refreshToken.js`

```
export const refreshTokenSetup = (res) => {
    let refreshTiming = (res.tokenObj.expires_in || 3600 - 5 * 60) * 1000;

    const refreshToken = async () => {
        const newAuthRes = await res.reloadAuthResponse();
        refreshTiming = (newAuthRes.expires_in || 3600 - 5 * 60) * 1000;
        console.log('newAuthRes:', newAuthRes);
        // saveUserToken(newAuthRes.access_token);  <-- save new token
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', newAuthRes.id_token);

        setTimeout(refreshToken, refreshTiming);
    };

    setTimeout(refreshToken, refreshTiming);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login

Based on the documentation, I guess you're trying to use `useGoogleLogin` instead of `GoogleLogin` ?

Check this section `Login Hook`

```
import { useGoogleLogin } from 'react-google-login'

const { signIn, loaded } = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess,
    ...
});
```

The problem is that you're calling a React component (i.e. `GoogleLogin`) as a function, it is a function indeed, but can only be called by React itself.

Comment: Appreciate your help. But unfortunately  nothing is happening !

Comment: @soccerway You mean the error still exists?

Comment: Yes, I have added the error details in the question.

Comment: I still see the original codes, can you possibly change it to the latest lines? Like `const {signIn} = GoogleLogin({` this line is definitely not the correct usage.

Comment: I have changed the code as per suggested in the question.

Comment: @soccerway The documentation seems not good enough so I checked the source code. The `signIn` returned by hook is a function, read here https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/use-google-login.js#L50

Comment: @soccerway So that `<button onClick={()=>signIn}>` this is not correct, you should just do `<button onClick={signIn}>`; Or `<button onClick={(e)=> { /*something more*/ signIn(e); }}>` if you like